# SQL gruoup by special condition and filter

Tags: sql

I have this data:

> Blockquote

| id_doc | id_exp | id_act | fecha |
| --- | --- | --- | --- |
| 500 | 2000 | 3 | 2021-10-23 |
| 501 | 2000 | 4 | NULL |
| 502 | 2000 | 6 | 2021-10-23 |
| 503 | 2000 | 2 | 2021-10-23 |
| 504 | 3000 | 4 | NULL |
| 505 | 3000 | 6 | 2021-10-23 |
| 506 | 4000 | 3 | 2021-10-23 |
| 507 | 4000 | 4 | NULL |

> Blockquote

I want show like this (only show id_act=4 and fecha is null) but show the same id_exp if id_act not in (2, 6):

> Blockquote

| id_doc | id_exp | id_act | fecha |
| --- | --- | --- | --- |
| 506 | 4000 | 3 | 2021-10-23 |
| 507 | 4000 | 4 | NULL |

Comment: Please post your sql so far

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can chekc WITH NOT EXISTS if one id_exp has a id_act in (2,6)

```
SELECT `id_doc`, `id_exp`, `id_act`, `fecha` FROM tab1
  WHERE `id_exp` IN 
(SELECT `id_exp`  FROM tab1 t1 WHERE 
     `id_act` = 4 and `fecha` IS  NULL
AND NOT EXISTS ( SELECT 1 FROM tab1 WHERE `id_act` IN (2,6) AND `id_exp` = t1.`id_exp` ))
```

| id_doc | id_exp | id_act | fecha |
| --- | --- | --- | --- |
| 506 | 4000 | 3 | 2021-10-23 |
| 507 | 4000 | 4 | *null* |

[fiddle](https://dbfiddle.uk/vI1MDKB3)